# Rellenar de color una parte de una gráfica curva

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

Como ejemplo, adjunto el código para dibujar la gráfica de una distribución normal. He conseguido rellenar de color todo su interior, pero lo que realmente quiero es rellanar solamente desde el extremos de la izquierda hasta la ordenada marcada con la letra "a".

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # importando matplotlib
# Graficando Normal

etiquetas = "Z"
x_pos = [1]
mu, sigma = 0, 1 # media y desvio estandar
normal = stats.norm(mu, sigma)
x = np.linspace(normal.ppf(0.01),
                normal.ppf(0.99), 100) # función e densidad de probabilidad

fp = normal.pdf(x) # Función de Probabilidad
plt.plot(x, fp)
plt.xticks(x_pos, etiquetas) 
plt.fill_between(x  , fp, facecolor="green", alpha= 0.2)
plt.vlines(1, ymin= 0,  ymax= 0.25, color = "blue", linestyles ="--")
plt.title('Distribución Normal')
plt.ylabel('probabilidad')
plt.xlabel('valores')
plt.show()
```

Agradeceré sus sugerencias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes usar el argumento `where` de [`matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html) para indicar una condición en base a los valores del eje `x`, `y` o ambos:

```
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # importando matplotlib
import numpy as np


# Graficando Normal
etiquetas = "Z"
x_pos = [1]
mu, sigma = 0, 1 # media y desvio estandar
normal = stats.norm(mu, sigma)
x = np.linspace(normal.ppf(0.01),
                normal.ppf(0.99), 100) # función e densidad de probabilidad

fp = normal.pdf(x) # Función de Probabilidad
plt.plot(x, fp)
plt.xticks(x_pos, etiquetas) 
xi = np.interp(0.25, x, fp)
plt.vlines(1, ymin= 0,  ymax= 0.25, color = "blue", linestyles ="--")
plt.fill_between(x, fp, where=x <= 1, facecolor="green", alpha= 0.2)
plt.title('Distribución Normal')
plt.ylabel('probabilidad')
plt.xlabel('valores')
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si quieres rellenar entre dos valores de x, dado que usas NumPy debes hacer:

```
plt.fill_between(
    x, fp, where=(0.5 <= x) & (x <= 1.5), facecolor="green", alpha= 0.2
    )
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias. ¿Y si la condición fuera esta: "0.5 <= x <= 1.5"?. Intento sin acierto con "where= (0.5 <= x).any() and  (x <= 1.5).any()" y "where= (0.5 <= x  <= 1.5).all()"

Comment: @efueyo he editado la respuesta, al final tienes la solución.